# Open last scroll position in UIWebView

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

I'm have a WebView:

```
func loadPage() {
    let request = NSURLRequest (URL: url!)
    myBrowser.loadRequest(request)
}
```

Which load RTF document from this URL:

```
var url: NSURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Chapter1", ofType: "rtf")!)!
```

How can I save last scroll position to NSUserDefaults, to get it then (if user pause reading and resume it).

Or maybe other type or method to make bookmark in this case.

**Note:** Ive been trying this:

```
var myBookmark: CGPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0)

override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
myBookmark = myBrowser.scrollView.contentOffset
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)
    myBrowser.scrollView.delegate = self
    myBrowser.scrollView.setContentOffset(myBookmark, animated: false)
}
```

But it's not take any effect.

UPD1: translate my VAR name.

Comment: What's закладка? Are you fetching it from NSUserDefaults?

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to translate it for quiestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To save and retrieve your scrollview offset from `NSUserDefaults`, set your `UIWebView`'s delegate and try this:

```
var viewLaidoutSubviews = false // <-- variable to prevent the viewDidLayoutSubviews code from happening more than once

// Save your content offset when the view disappears
override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    var userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    userDefaults.setValue(NSStringFromCGPoint(myBrowser.scrollView.contentOffset), forKey: "scroll_offset")
    userDefaults.synchronize()

    viewLaidoutSubviews = false
}

// Retrieve and set your content offset when the view re-appears
// and its subviews are first laid out
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {

    if (!viewLaidoutSubviews) {
        // If a scroll_offset is store in NSUserDefaults, use it
        var userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        var scrollOffset:CGPoint? = CGPointFromString(userDefaults.valueForKey("scroll_offset") as? NSString)
        if let position:CGPoint = scrollOffset {
            myBrowser.scrollView.delegate = self
            myBrowser.scrollView.setContentOffset(position, animated: false)
        }
        viewLaidoutSubviews = true
    }
}
```

And utilize you `UIWebView`'s `webViewDidFinishLoad` delegate method to update the scroll offset in the case that the web view didn't finish rendering before the view laid out its subviews:

```
// Retrieve and set your content offset once the web view has
// finished rendering (in case it hasn't finished rendering
// by the time the view's subviews were laid out)
func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView) {

    // If a scroll_offset is store in NSUserDefaults, use it
    var userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    var scrollOffset:CGPoint? = CGPointFromString(userDefaults.valueForKey("scroll_offset") as? NSString)
    if let position:CGPoint = scrollOffset {
        myBrowser.scrollView.delegate = self
        myBrowser.scrollView.setContentOffset(position, animated: true)
    }
}
```

But note, your `NSUserDefaults` value will also persist between app launches unless you delete it.

Comment: Thank you for response.
Early I get a (0, 0) contentOffset when viewWillAppear even if the viewWillDisappear set a contentOffset to my last scroll position.

Now contentOffset set's normally, but WebView all the same open's from the top. (

Comment: @Jauzee I'm not sure I understand what you're saying... Is the scrollOffset being retrieved from NSUserDefaults correctly? When you println("\(scrollOffset.x), \(scrollOffset.y)") within the if let block, is the value what you expected?

Comment: @Jauzee And you shouldn't use the same "myBookmark" variable name in your `if let` statement as you do for your global variable. I've changed the second `myBookmark` value in my code to `position` to show you what I mean.

Comment: @Jauzee In fact, in your current code, there's no need to create that `myBookmark` global variable.

Comment: scrollOffset retrieves NSUserDefaults. for ex. "Optional((0.0,752.0))", but webview view appears from the top, etc. setContenrOffset doesn't effect.

Comment: Thank you. I am delete this global var.

Comment: @Jauzee OK, so you're receiving the proper value from NSUserDefaults. Move the `viewWillAppear` code to `viewDidLayoutSubviews` instead because it sounds like it's not offsetting due to auto layout. But you're only going to want the code to happen once. I'll update my answer to show you what I mean.

Comment: @Jauzee Great. Updated to set animation to true. :)

Comment: I'm hurried. Your solution works, but scroll down to wrong position. For ex. If userDefaults saved a (0.0, 1420.0) position, webview opens on (0.0, 800.0)- it scroll's not enough to stored position. Excuse me for lot of questions.

Comment: @Jauzee It works for me... And actually I'm going to change the animation back to false because it looks better without the initial animation. I wonder why it's not working for you... Perhaps your WebView hasn't finished completely loading by the time the view appears? When in your code are you loading the page?

Comment: In viewDidLoad by call a function loadPage(). If i switch off animation it doesn't work anyway.

Comment: @Jauzee Yeah, like I said, I think your UIWebView hasn't finished rendering by the time the viewDidLayoutSubviews is called... I'll make an updated with a suggestion...

Comment: @Jauzee OK, I've updated my code with a suggestion to use the `UIWebView` delegate method `webViewDidFinishLoad` instead of `viewDidLayoutSubviews` so that the scroll updates once the view has finished rendering. Just make sure to set the web view's delegate to self and add the `UIWebViewDelegate` to your class.

Comment: @Jauzee OK, perfect. :)